# how to add processing instruction in xml using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, processing-instruction

I am writing a XML using `XmlDocument`, I need a element or attribute like shown below

The element or attribute required is  `<?Validversion="1" ?>`

how to create using xmldocument or xmlwriter.

```
        // to create <?Validversion="1" ?>
        XmlDocument aDoc = new XmlDocument();
        aDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null);
        XmlCDataSection aDataSec =aDoc.CreateCDataSection("?Version = 2");
        aDoc.AppendChild(aDataSec);
        aDoc.Save("c:\\vector.xml");
```

Comment: How does the xml that you want to generate look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [XmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createprocessinginstruction%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and not CDATA section:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.AppendChild(document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", null));
var  piNode = document.CreateProcessingInstruction("Version", "=\"2\"");
document.AppendChild(pi);
```

Side note: don't forget to `AppendChild` newly created node.